# jQuery document complete load with images, iframes and Ajax's calls

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am developing for a client some modules for his online store ( shipping price, invoices and others ), and this modules are loading in pre-checkout page with ajax. By now I have 5-6 Ajax's requests at the same time and the loading page is medium-height.

I want to display a bootstrap 3.2.1 modal that will init in the beginning of the page and after (when everything is done - inclusive Ajax's) will hide and destroy.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#loadCart').modal('show');
</script>
```

This script is adding just after modal HTML declaration and just after `<body>` statement

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function () {
        $(window).load(function() {
            $('#loadCart').modal('hide');
        });
    });
</script>
```

and this script is adding just before closing `</body>` statement.

So ... the main question is .. how can I find when all Ajax's from this page are done, to know when to destroy & hide the modal defined?

Comment: `this script is adding just before close </body>` FYI, then document ready handler is useless.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/) event handler:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $('#loadCart').modal('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

so & so....

the modal window stay a long time on screen but... is hidding before loading all ajax's requests on page....

```
AjaxRequest = function( encrypted_reqFile, encrypted_formObj, responseObj ) {
    var data = encrypted_formObj;
    $(responseObj).html('<img src="/wp-content/themes/ergala/images/loading.gif" />');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/wp-content/themes/ergala/jsonx.php',
        data: { 'data': data, 'reqFile' : reqFile },
        success: function ( responseText ) {
            $( responseObj ).html( responseText );
        }
    });

}
```

this function is executed when I call every ajax on this page. I think the problem is this function is not returning `.done()` function when ajax call is complete or i dont know `.always()`